# To authenticate in nodejs using paginated endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to node.js development. I have a scenario where there is a endpoint

eg : `https://example.co/api/people/?page=2`

sample Response would be

```
{
"count": 87,
"next": "https://example.co/api/people/?page=3",
"previous": "https://example.co/api/people/?page=1",
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Skywalker",
        "birth_year": "41.9BBY",
        "homeworld": "https://example.co/api/planets/1/",
        "created": "2014-12-10T16:20:44.310000Z",
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.327000Z",
        "url": "https://example.co/api/people/11/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Wilhuff",
        "birth_year": "64BBY",
        "created": "2014-12-10T16:26:56.138000Z",
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.330000Z",
        "url": "https://example.co/api/people/12/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Chewbacca",
        "birth_year": "200BBY",
        "created": "2014-12-10T16:42:45.066000Z",
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.332000Z",
        "url": "https://example.co/api/people/13/"
    }

]
}
```

Which will give results of page 2 if query param page=2.

If I give `https://example.co/api/people/`, by default it is giving result of page 1.

From front-end, I have a login page, where username and dob are the inputs for `loginId` and `password` respectively.

When I get login Id, password data from front-end, I Would call a common endpoint to authenticate "https://example.co/api/people/authenticate" which in-turn calls the "https://example.co/api/people/?page=2" endpoint which has many pages. If given input matches with any of pages results,it should return a success message.

How would I authenticate the inputs in back-end from that particular endpoint which has may pages.

Could someone please suggest a approach.

Comment: "How would I authenticate the inputs in back-end from that particular endpoint which has may pages." - This doesn't make a ton of sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: After you login, does the response give you a key? What form of authentication do the other endpoints expect? Is it JWT, Bearer, Token, or etc.?

Comment: @JordanS   From front-end, i will call a endpoint "https://example.co/api/people/authenticate" by giving login id,dob in request body. In backend, i should utilise the endpoint "https://example.co/api/people/?page=2" which has different pages and should check if both inputs matches in any of results and should return success message

Answer (score 0):

```
 listPeople: function(req, res) {
    var perPage = 10;
    var page = (Math.abs(req.body.people.currentPage) || 1);
    req.query.limit = 10;
    var limit = Math.abs(req.query.limit) || 10;
      page = req.body.people.currentPage > 0 ? req.body.people.currentPage : 0
    People
      .find({})
      .limit(perPage)
      .skip(perPage * page)
      .sort({
        name: 'asc'
      }).exec(function(err, peopleRecords) {
        if (people.length) {
          People.count().exec(function(err, count) {
            return res.status(200).send({
              peopleRecords: peopleRecords,
              page: page,
              pages: count / perPage
            });
          })
        }
      });
  },
```

Here I am adding simple example that I am using...

Just You need to pass `perPage` how many records you want?
`currentPage` which is your current Page.

Hope this helps :-)